# Utilizando o Helper do Codeigniter (Download_helper)

Tags: codeigniter, mvc, helper

Boa noite! Estou utilizando a função `force_download()` para realizar o download de um arquivo. Contudo, preciso fazer esse mesmo procedimento, mas com o download de vários arquivos ao mesmo tempo. Implementei um código, a lógica que utilizei não está realizando tal procedimento. Alguém pode me dar uma dica do que posso fazer?

Controller:

```
 public function download($id = NULL){
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $download = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE protocolo_id ='.$id);
    foreach ($download->result() as $itens){
        $diretorio = file_get_contents('./uploads/'.$itens->arquivo);         
        $arquivo = $itens->arquivo;
        force_download($arquivo, $diretorio);      
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que recomendo pra você é usar a library `Zip` para adicionar seus arquivos em um compactado e então baixa-los: Abaixo sua função de forma similar, que, acredito atender sua necessidade:

```
public function download($id = NULL){
    $this->load->library('zip');

    $download = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE protocolo_id ='.$id);

    foreach ($download->result() as $itens){
        $this->zip->add_data('./uploads/'.$itens->arquivo, file_get_contents('./uploads/'.$itens->arquivo));
    }

    if($download->num_rows() > 0){
        $this->zip->archive('/path/arquivos.zip');
        $this->zip->download('arquivos.zip');
    }
}
```

Comment: Teoricamente funcionou, só que quando extraiu o arquivo zip, não exibi as imagens. diz: "O Visualizar de fotos do Windows não pode abrir esta imagem porque não oferece suporte a este formato...." Sendo o problema só nos arquivos que faço download. Tem alguma configuração a se fazer?

Comment: Funcionou sim, só mudei a posição do `file_get_contents` como segundo parâmetro. Pois o primeiro é o nome do arquivo e o segundo é o conteúdo do arquivo. Tanks!